# Is it permissible to teach a non-muslim student?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, education

If I start tuition a student who is non-muslim. Is it be permissible for me to provide tuition?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be permissible? Elaborate!

Comment: More details please! What subject are we talking about? Gender difference? Family? Any issue that makes you think not permissible?

Comment: I am a muslim male. If I provide tuition a non-muslim girl or a boy, is it be permissible?

Comment: Tutoring is a form of labor (ijarah). If it is permitted to perform for a Muslim it is also permitted to perform for a non-muslim, as there is no prohibition (as long as it is not demeaning) and permissible tasks can be undertaken for a non-muslim , you may find that there is a hadith that Ali drew buckets of water for a Jew.

Comment: @RakibulHassan Remember that Maharam and Non-Maharam rules will still apply.

Comment: You should add any useful information into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's permissible to tutor a non-Muslim. Just as importantly, you should be qualified to teach. The qualification of course will depend upon the subject under question and the level you are teaching.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is fine to tutor a non-Muslim. it's like asking if a white person can teach a black person. As long as you are being safe and responsible while tutoring the person, then your good