# Tuition to the other siblings of same gender

Tags: quran, hadith, sharia, islamic-philosophy

If I provide tuitions to two-sibling girls at a time where I am the opposite gender, is it permissible for me to provide tuition in order to earning money?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it permissible to teach a non-muslim student?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63672/is-it-permissible-to-teach-a-non-muslim-student)

Comment: Please avoid writing [duplicates](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63672/is-it-permissible-to-teach-a-non-muslim-student) of your own question! It is better to edit your question by using the "edit" link!